# country & Year -Last Modified date

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to split the country and year from the file name order by `LastWriteTime` and want to move the remaining file to archive folder by year wise but can only filter the year not and not the country name
CODE:

```
$sourcedir = 'C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files\Advisory_rate'
$destdir   = 'C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files\Advisory_rate\Archive'
Get-ChildItem -File -Path $sourcedir |
    Where-Object BaseName -match '_(20\d{2})_\d' |
    Group-Object $Matches[1] |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.Group | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
            Select-Object -Skip 1 |
            Move-Item -Destination $destdir -Force 
    }
```

Output is

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length  Name
----                -------------     ------  ----
-a---         6/25/2018  12:08 AM      31744  abc Italy_2016_2 - Copy - Copy.xls
-a---         6/25/2018  12:07 AM      31744  abc Italy_2016_2 - Copy.xls
-a---         6/25/2018  12:06 AM      31744  abc China_2017_1.xls
-a---         6/25/2018  12:07 AM      31744  abc NL_2017_2.xls
-a---         6/25/2018  12:05 AM      31744  abc Finland_2017_3.xls
```

In above data row 2 will go to archive because last write time of Italy for the year 2016 is 12:08.
I am trying to split the name via `Group-Object {$_.Basename.Split(' ')[2]}`, but am unable to use in above condition

```
also tried:Where-Object BaseName -match ' ([a-z]+_20\d{2})_\d' | &  Where-Object BaseName -match '_(20\d{2})_\d' |

$sourcedir = 'C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files\Advisory_rate'
$destdir   = 'C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files\Advisory_rate\Archive'
Get-ChildItem -File -Path $sourcedir |
Where-Object BaseName -match ' ([a-z]+_20\d{2})_\d' |
    Group-Object $Matches[1] |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.Group | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
            Select-Object -Skip 1 |
            Move-Item -Destination $destdir -Force 
    }

both conditions are tried separately gives the error message:

Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files\Script\Tracker.ps1:3 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem -File -Path $sourcedir |
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

I think the issue is in the Group-Object $Matches[1] |...if I remove this query is not giving an error...do I have to define this $matches

```
--Unable to find country and year when the file name is changed
abc N Refund Maker_Japan_2017_302413 modified date :26/06 10:20
abc N Refund Maker_Japan_2017_Extra  modified date:26/06 10:30
```

tried new regexp:

```
$sourcedir = 'C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files\Advisory_rate'
$destdir   = 'C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files\Advisory_rate\Archive'

Get-ChildItem -File -Path $sourcedir |
  Where-Object BaseName -match '_([a-z]+_20\d{2})_\d'|
    Group-Object {$Matches[1]} |
      ForEach-Object {
        $_.Group | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
          Select-Object -Skip 1 |
            Move-Item -Destination $destdir -Force 
      }
but file is not moving
abc N Refund Maker_Japan_2017_302413 modified date :26/06 10:20
abc N Refund Maker_Japan_2017_Extra  modified date:26/06 10:30
abc N Refund Macker_Italy_2017_302413 modified date :26/06 10:20 
abc N Refund Macker_Italy_2017_extra modified date :26/06 10:30


i got new  logic  into it and getting output also how fix this in the query

   $Match = "[^_]+_[0-9]{4}"
$Lines = get-clipboard
$Results = $Lines | %{$_ -Match $Match | %{$Matches[0]}}

output:

Japan_2017
Japan_2017
Italy_2017
Italy_2017
```

this is what expected
ok...giving a fresh example...these are the four files ....in this case...needs to group by country and year.... then max last modified 
file will be there and other file will move archive for that country 
and year...so here 2nd and 3rd file will go to the archive....simple way country and year are repeated for two times in example.....so less modified date file will go to the archive for that year and country...

```
abc N Refund Maker_Japan_2017_302413 modified date :26/06 10:20
abc N Refund Maker_Japan_2017_Extra  modified date:26/06 10:30
abc N Refund Macker_Italy_2017_302413 modified date :26/06 10:20 
abc N Refund Macker_Italy_2017_xyz modified date :26/06 10:30
```

Comment: Change the RegEx in the Where to include the country, so the grouping includes it also: `Where-Object BaseName -match ' ([a-z]+_20\d{2})_\d' |`

Comment: The error you report has nothing to do with the where-object, looks like the variable $sourcedir isn't populated.

Comment: Of course, what do you expect? The RegEx can't magially adapt to the new format.

Comment: if the new format encloses the country with underscores the RegEx is `'_([a-z]+_20\d{2})_\d'`

Comment: Your initial scheme had a digit following the year_ which excludes the `Extra` this is a not neccessary part of the RegEx, so remove the `\d` at the end of the RegEx.

Comment: yes..whenever i add 2 more files the formula goes off....any specific reason...the below-mentioned file 2nd file should got to archive which is not happening


Payment N Refund Tracker_USA_2017_erf  last modified date 12/07 04:47 AM

Payment N Refund Tracker_USA_2017_erfc  last modified date    12/07 04:45 AM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my fault. You have to put curly braces around `$Matches[1]` in the Group-Object

```
$sourcedir = 'C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files\Advisory_rate'
$destdir   = 'C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files\Advisory_rate\Archive'

Get-ChildItem -File -Path $sourcedir |
  Where-Object BaseName -match ' ([a-z]+_20\d{2})_\d' |
    Group-Object {$Matches[1]} |
      ForEach-Object {
        $_.Group | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
          Select-Object -Skip 1 |
            Move-Item -Destination $destdir -Force 
      }
```

Tested with different pathes

```
> ls
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       2018-07-09     23:04                Archive
-a----       2018-06-25     12:06              6 abc China_2017_1.xls
-a----       2018-06-25     12:05              6 abc Finland_2017_3.xls
-a----       2018-06-25     12:08              6 abc Italy_2016_2 - Copy - Copy.xls
-a----       2018-06-25     12:07              6 abc NL_2017_2.xls


PoSh 23:04:43 A:\test_______________________________________________________________
> gci .\Archive\
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2018-06-25     12:07              6 abc Italy_2016_2 - Copy.xls
```

Answer (score 0):

Another answer changed only details (can't understand why you do have problems)

These files

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2018-06-26     10:20              6 abc N Refund Macker_Italy_2017_302413
-a----       2018-06-26     10:30              6 abc N Refund Macker_Italy_2017_xyz
-a----       2018-06-26     10:20              6 abc N Refund Maker_Japan_2017_302413
-a----       2018-06-26     10:30              6 abc N Refund Maker_Japan_2017_Extra
```

and this script:

```
## Q:\Test\2018\07\09\SO_51242305.ps1
$sourcedir = 'C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files\Advisory_rate'
$destdir   = 'C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files\Advisory_rate\Archive'

$sourcedir = 'A:\Test'
$destdir   = 'A:\Test\Archive'

Get-ChildItem -File -Path $sourcedir |
  Where-Object BaseName -match '_([a-z]+_20\d{2})_' |
    Group-Object {$Matches[1]} |
      ForEach-Object {
        $_.Group | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
          Select-Object -Skip 1 |
            Move-Item -Destination $destdir -Force
      }
```

get this output:

```
> gci $sourcedir -r
    Verzeichnis: A:\Test

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       2018-07-12     20:15                Archive
-a----       2018-06-26     10:30              6 abc N Refund Macker_Italy_2017_xyz
-a----       2018-06-26     10:30              6 abc N Refund Maker_Japan_2017_Extra

    Verzeichnis: A:\Test\Archive

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2018-06-26     10:20              6 abc N Refund Macker_Italy_2017_302413
-a----       2018-06-26     10:20              6 abc N Refund Maker_Japan_2017_302413
```